# What does boto stand for

Tags: boto, boto3

What does Boto stand for in the context of AWS?  It seems like a random word to choose for an api name.  Is it an acronym?  I have tried googling around and see no indication of what it could mean.

Comment: This question is off topic for stackoverflow as it isn't a programming question. See github for an answer: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1023#issuecomment-287127647

Comment: This is not off-topic:  The meaning of a name can be insightful into what it is naming.  For example, the [meaning of the OCaml programming language name](https://ocaml.org/learn/faq.html).  In the case of Boto here, it does not seem to relate to anything technical about AWS or Python - but the Question here is helpful nonetheless to rule that possibility out.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Boto derives its name from the Portuguese name given to types of dolphins native to the Amazon River.

SO, I don't think it stands for anything or it has full form.
Though this could only be best answered by the Team of AWS, who has come up with this name, but [documentation](https://searchaws.techtarget.com/definition/Boto) suggests, what I have written at the start.

[image]

Its just catchy name and has some link the Amazon and the Amazon River

Comment: There are dolphins in the Amazon river??

Comment: @jimh really good question that forced me to do a quick check on the internet, and to answer your questions, in fact YES!, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_river_dolphin

Comment: you're blowing my mind sir

Answer (score 10):

From internal Wiki:

> The Boto was named after it because it swims in the Amazon, and all
> the good river and city names were already taken.

Comment: Taken by who...?

Answer (score 2):

From the [creator](https://github.com/garnaat):

> It was named after the fresh water dolphin native to the Amazon river. I wanted something short, unusual, and with at least some kind of connection to Amazon. Boto seemed to fit the bill 8^)

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1023#issuecomment-287127647